# PubSub Avro schema with JSON array throws Invalid schema definition error

Tags: avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm setting up a pub/sub topic to receive some JSON data. One of the fields in the JSON data is an array of strings, like so:

```
{
    ...
    "Tags": ["2333TAG"],
    ...
}
```

I've tried defining the schema as per the [Avro 1.11 spec](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/_print/):

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Avro",
  "fields": [
    ...
    {
      "name": "Tags",
      "type": "array",
      "items": "string",
      "default": []
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

But when I try to validate the definition, I get the error: `Invalid schema definition: Reference node does not refer to previously declared type: array`

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? I have verified that this is the field in the schema that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avro requires a nested type for declaring an `array`:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Avro",
  "fields": [
    ...
    {
      "name": "Tags",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string",
        "default": []
      }
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: That solved it. Wasn't really clear that's how you had to do it in the Avro docs. Thanks!